# ExtJS timefield 24 hour format picker

Tags: extjs, timefield

I'm using ExtJS 7.3.1 (modern) and I have a problem with the `timefield` picker. I can't find a solution to let the user choose directly in the 24hour format without switch between AM and PM option ... is it possible?
In the visualization no problem, because there is the `format` property ('H:i').

Comment: sorry modern toolkit

Comment: in the sample fiddle of sencha we can see the AM/PM option in the picker: fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/32ki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you would have to set the [meridiem](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.panel.Time.html#cfg-meridiem) config of the picker to false:

```js
{
    xtype: 'timefield',
    label: 'Birthday',
    format: 'H:i',
    picker: {
        meridiem: false
    }
}
```

[image]

Also note, there is [alignPMInside](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.panel.Time.html#cfg-alignPMInside) config (also on the picker), that when set to `true`, will align the hours in two circles:

```js
{
    xtype: 'timefield',
    label: 'Birthday',
    format: 'H:i',
    picker: {
        meridiem: false,
        alignPMInside: true
    }
}
```

[image]